# iOS swift. MKMap, user location stuck on right side of screen

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit

I have a `mapKit` on a `view controller`. I want the `map` to show the users current location. it seems to work but the users location is stuck on the right hand side of the screen. when you try scrolling it away from the right it just pops back there. Cannot fathom what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    clientAddressTextField.text = clientAddress
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true  
 }

 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Kind regards

Wayne

Comment: Have you set your map view constraints?  Sounds like it is half offscreen

Comment: Thank you, I cannot believe I forgot something like that. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have set constraints for your map view, otherwise it will have some default size & location, which may well be offscreen

Answer (score -1):

Use the mapView's delegate method mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800), animated: true)
}
```